# docker centos6.8 enabling ipv6

Tags: docker, centos6

I've pulled the latest centos6.8 container

```
docker run -it hub.docker.com/centos:centos6.8 /bin/bash
```

and I've executed `ipconfig` inside the container which shows

```
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 b)
```

What can I do to enable ipv6? i.e have an inet6 addr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable ipv6 at the level of the Docker deamon. This is documented under [Enable IPv6 support](https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/ipv6/).

Comment: thank you. now im getting this error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49067842/docker-cannot-connect-to-overlay-ipv6-network