# Docker cannot connect to overlay ipv6 network

Tags: docker

I've created docker network

```
docker network create --driver=overlay --ipv6 --attachable cqxipv6
```

`docker network inspect cqxipv6` shows

```
    {
        "Name": "cqxipv6",
        "Id": "u1t2l7jdze89sey8j9oed9az8",
        "Created": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
        "Scope": "swarm",
        "Driver": "overlay",
        "EnableIPv6": true,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": []
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": true,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": null,
        "Options": {
            "com.docker.network.driver.overlay.vxlanid_list": "4098"
        },
        "Labels": null
    }
]
```

I've tried to run a container using the created network

```
docker run -it --name mydocker --rm --network cqxipv6 hub.docker.com/centos:centos6.8 /bin/bash
```

And I am getting this error

```
docker: Error response from daemon: attaching to network failed, make sure your network options are correct and check manager logs: context deadline exceeded.
```

Any idea what this mean and how to fix it?

Thank you

Comment: In first place why would you want and overlay network to run a single container? In normal scenario you use an overlay network to create a distributed network among multiple Docker daemon hosts. For Swarm mode. As you see on your network inspect command the scope is set to Swarm. That's why your command throws an Error

Comment: @RavinduFernando it's not for single container. I was testing to see if /sbin/ifconfig would show ::1 ipv6 for lo

Comment: Did the answer fix your problem?

Answer (score 0):

the problem dissappeared after supplying subnet

```
docker network create --driver overlay --ipv6 --subnet=2001:3984:3989::/80 --attachable cqxipv6
```